# What logic is behind NaN evaluation?

Tags: javascript, nan, logical-operators

Can you explain the logical evaluation of `NaN` in javascript?

```
NaN==NaN   (false)
!NaN==!NaN (true)
NaN!=NaN   (true)
NaN==false (false)
NaN==true  (false)
```

I am a little surprised here...

Comment: For a humourous take on this sort of thing, see [https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat)

Comment: What *exactly* are you surprised about?

Comment: @FelixKling - that JS implements three values in boolean logic: true, false and falsy

Comment: @JanTuroň: What do you mean by that? Maybe my comment on SLaks answer clarifies it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that's what the spec says.

Specifically, the IEE floating point spec says that `NaN` does not equal itself.
Therefore, in Javascript, there is no value that `NaN` can ever equal.

`!NaN` is `true`, because `NaN` is a falsy value.

This makes all of your examples obvious.

Comment: OK, but how should I comprehend the negation of such value? My brain hurts...

Comment: And it also implies !NaN == false (false) and !NaN == true (true) what's true

Comment: @JanTuroň: The result of using `!` is a Boolean value. So if you use `!NaN==!NaN `, then you are comparing to Booleans with each other, not `NaN`. If that's what you meant. Converting a value to a Boolean and comparing a value to another value are two different things. Only because `!NaN` is `true` doesn't mean that `NaN == false` (that's because `NaN` is not converted to a Boolean in this process).